# How to change breakpoints in the scss in vuetify v2?

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, vuetify.js

I'm using scss files and I want to change the breakpoints in the css side in vuetify v2.

I Can't find any reference in vuetify upgrade guide for this.

In version 1.5 I did style-x.styl:

```
$grid-breakpoints := {
  xs: 0
  sm: 476px
  md: 668px
  lg: 1000px
  xl: 1300px
}
@import '~vuetify/src/styles/styles.sass';

$material-light.background = #f5f5f5;

@import '~vuetify/src/stylus/main';
```

And then I import the file:

```
import '../style-x.styl';
...
Vue.use(Vuetify);
...
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For version 2.0 you have to change the SASS variables by creating a custom SASS file which you import into your vue.config.js file: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/sass-variables.

For the SASS variables to be available globally, you can to first

```
// src/sass/main.scss
@import '~vuetify/src/styles/styles.sass';

// You need to map-merge your new SASS variables
$grid-breakpoints: map-merge($grid-breakpoints, (
  xs: 0,
  sm: 476px,
  md: 668px,
  lg: 1000px,
  xl: 1300px
))
```

And then have your config file import the variable globally:

```
// vue.config.js

module.exports = {
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        data: `@import "~@/sass/main.scss"`,
      },
    },
  },
}
```

You also have to specify your custom breakpoints when you specify Vuetify options:
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/breakpoints

```
//import this into your main.js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'

export default new Vuetify({
  breakpoint: {
    thresholds: {
       xs: 0,
       sm: 476,
       md: 668,
       lg: 1000,
       xl: 1300
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Ok - I've added to my response to clarify the scss part.

Comment: Oops! Tiny mistake. It should be $grid-breakpoints:, with a colon not an equal sign.

Comment: thresholds shouldnt have px after the numbers

Comment: Does not work. I get an error message that data is an invalid option.

Answer (score 11):

So look at the documentation: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/sass-variables/#vue-cli-install, it says:

> Once installed, create a folder called sass, scss or styles in your
>   src directory with a file named variables.scss or variables.sass

That is, after we have created the project using the **Vue CLI**, we manually:

1. Сreate the new **sass** folder in our **src** folder.
2. Next, in our new **sass** folder, create the new **variables.scss** file.
3. Next, in our new **variables.scss** file, write these lines, these
   are the standard settings for bootstrap-4:

*

```
$grid-breakpoints: (
  xs: 0,
  sm: 576px,
  md: 768px,
  lg: 992px,
  xl: 1200px
);
```

4. Now restart **npm run serve** and you are ready. You can change the values in the $grid-breakpoints variable to your own.

Comment: This one works as it says in the documentation. no need to touch the `vue.config.js` file.