# Vuetify responsive grid gutters using breakpoints

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

Is it possible to change the size of the gutters between the grid columns depending on the breakpoints?

For example: On a large display, I want the gutters to be 24px and anything less than or equal to a medium device, I want it to have 16px gutters.

Vuetify v2.6.6

Comment: does [How to change breakpoints in the scss in vuetify v2?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57333645/11260991) answer your question

Comment: No, it is necessary to change adaptively gutters (distance between columns)

Comment: Inside v-data-table ?

Comment: `v-row` does not support variable gutter size - the only prop you have under your disposal is `dense` which you can set based on `$vuetify.breakpoint` [service](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/breakpoints/#breakpoint-service-object). So you will have either dense or normal gutters.

Comment: In older versions of vuetify we had the `grid-list-{size}` prop for `v-container` to change the size of the gutters. Not sure in current version, might need to ask in the discord server.

Comment: Looks like in current version all we have is the prop `dense` and `no-gutters` for the `v-row`

Answer (score 0):

I asked myself the very same question, and looking at the [vuetify source code](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/components/VGrid/VGrid.sass#L20), I managed to write this:

```
@media #{map-get($display-breakpoints, 'md-and-down')} {
  .row {
    margin: -$form-grid-gutter / 2;
    margin-top: $form-grid-gutter / 2;
    & + .row {
      margin-top: $form-grid-gutter / 2;
    }
    & > .col,
    & > [class*='col-'] {
      padding: $form-grid-gutter / 2;
    }
  }
}
```

Which is imported in `layouts/default.vue`.

As a reminder, `$form-grid-gutter` is the variable used when using [the `dense` prop of the grid](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-row/#props-dense) so it emulates that any `v-row`/`v-col` has the `dense` property when the screen is `md` or down.

Any other scss variable could be used.